# Unable to select records between date range

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

In my Windows Form C# Application, I am inserting the record into the SQL server database. Along with other fields, I am also inserting both the current date and current time using the following format:

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
string SaleDate = currentDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
string SaleTime = currentTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
```

Which works fine and the records are inserted successfully with Date and Time format like [image: this].

However, when I select records between two dates, I am unable to perform this operation. I am sure that there is no problem in this custom format of my date because I have edited the same format several times and even I have saved the date in its default format but still I am unable to select the target records (between two dates)

I am using the following select query in my application to select records from the view `vAllSales` which results in selecting either all the records or records whose SaleDate does not meet the specified filter criteria:

```
select * from vAllSales where SaleDate >= '20-04-2019' and SaleDate <= '30-04-2019'"
```

I have tried the following queries in my SQL server as well to inspect the cause:

1.

```
select * from vAllSales where SaleDate between '21-04-2019' and '09-05-2019'
```

The above query does not return any value. Like [image: this]

2.

```
select * from vAllSales where SaleDate >= '21-04-2019'
```

The above query select only a few records. Because `21-04-2019` is the initial `SaleDate` and the query should return all of the `Sales` but it only returns a few records, like [image: this].

Is there any issue with the specified date format within my code? Or do I have to work on improving my queries? I need a more professional and reliable approach for this case.

Comment: Could well be down to datetime format. What you probably want to do though is use parameters (which should solve it); taking plain text like that will leave you open to SQL injection. This link may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements

Comment: You saving date and time as a string, so query will treat dates in database as a string. Save them in the column of type DateTime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store your date and time as [datetime2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) objects in your database.

It will give you the benefits of:

- better sorting: (your current string format does not allow a natural sort)
- better performance; since your date and times are represented as numbers in stead of strings
- easier to handle in code and queries: since it maps directly to a C# `DateTime` object.

For more info on database types see:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

And perhaps:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

---

If you absolutely must use a string to represent your date, make sure it's in the [sort-able ISO format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

due to the nature of this format it's [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) sort-able as a string type.

Comment: The sortable ISO Format works for me. Instead of using the format `dd-MM-yyyy`, I used `yyyy-MM-dd` and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to apply logical operations to string values. What will here happen is [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) comparing. (left to right).

So you better use correct [data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to store data in table.

But If you really want to store date as a string, you have to cast them to proper data types before comparison.

```
select * from vAllSales where  CAST(SaleDate AS DATE) >= '21-04-2019'
```

Keep note that ms sql server uses single quotes for pass datetimes. That doesn't mean those are strings or varchar